# Cannot open blender 2.79 on blender in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, downloads, blender, extract

Hello so i have installed blender 2.79 from https://www.blender.org/download/releases/2-79/ and extract it and i tried to open the blender program from the extracted file and it wont open it doesent show any error it just dosent open.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this answer with a warning that Blender 2.79 is an outdated, unsupported version of the software from 2017. If your system is able, you should install a current release version or at the very least use a release that gets [long term support](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/).

---

Blender 2.79 isn't supported under Ubuntu 20.04 repositories. It also isn't supported by Blender under the LTS designation.

However, it does appear that you can install this version using Snap.

To install the outdated Blender 2.79b as a Snap, you need to run the following command:

```
sudo snap install blender --channel=2.79/stable --classic
```